# Sharepoint (external) applications catalog design - choosing the adequate component

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm making an internal corporative Sharepoint site. I want to make page "Application catalog" page which lists the web aps we made (Asp net core aps hosted on corporative IIS).

Each item should have a picture, a title, a short description and few links below the app which represents the links for navigation to the apps and some of the apps functionalities.

In the attached picture (Sharepoint site screenshot I found on the internet) I want to show you the look I want to achieve for my own site. I think I tried all of the possible Sharepoint components (Image, Link,...) but I didn't manage to recreate the same design from the attached image.

Does anybody knows what is the component used in the image, or knows a way how to recreate this specific design?[image: design I want to recreate]

I tried using Sharepoint link, Image, Sites... But had no success.